# How to show all subreports one after one according to its detail sections record count

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm new to crystal reports, i thought what i want is quit difficult for me
so my query is like
i have 3 subreports, in my main report with 3 detail section for it in main report
now i want to print that report in way that

```
Header1_of_subreport1
     detail section with only 4 records

Header1_of_subreport2
     detail section with only 4 records

Header1_of_subreport3
     detail section with only 4 records
```

in 1 page only
then again on next page continue with 5th record
for 4 records i applied new page after formula for 4 records on 1 page, 
thats why its showing like

```
Header1_section1
  detail with 4 records  --------------1st page
Header1_section1
  5 th records  --------------2nd page
Header1_section2
  detail with 4 records  --------------3rd page
```

cnt like this

so how i can get that one??

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to control the sub report view with number of records but crystal works in a way that `once it finishes all records of sub report1 then only it will go to sub report 2` and the process continues till all sub reports are completed.

To the extent I know we can't control this behaviour and your requirement is difficult to achieve..

`Also Tag your question with Crystal reports along crystal reports 2008 so that it is visible to many people`